# Why does powershell keep returning a System.Object when i run the Get-AzStorageShare command within powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, object, azure-storage

I am trying to create a script to remove azure directories automatically and one of the issues I have run into is with the Get-AzStorageShare command. It seems to be returning the wrong object type.

Currently I am running this command to check for the share

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$ctx.ToString()

[Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.CloudFileShare]$S = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $ctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|Select-Object {$_.Name -eq $AzShare }
```

When I run this command by itself it shows **true** but when I run it with the next command to check the directory

```
$d = Get-AzStorageFile -Share $S -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|select Name
```

It will return the error

> Get-AzStorageFile : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.CloudFileShare' required by parameter

When I check the type of $S it does show that its a System.Object. I have tried naming the object type in a few different areas as well as calling the object a couple different ways but so far it hasn't helped. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `[]` after `object` in the type name `[object[]]` means it's an _array_ - you're passing multiple objects at once. Try `$ctx |ForEach-Object { Get-AzStorageShare -Context $_ }` instead

Answer (score 0):

> Get-AzStorageFile : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.CloudFileShare' required by parameter

I agree with Mathias R. Jessen's Comment the error indicates that you are passing an array of objects instead of a single object.

To retrieve a single object, you can use the **`Where-Object cmdlet`** instead of **`Select-Object`**.

**Script:**

```
$StorageAccountName="xxxx"
$StorageAccountKey="xxxxx"
$AzShare="xxxx"
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$S = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $ctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where-Object {$_.Name -eq $AzShare }
$d = Get-AzStorageFile -Share $s.CloudFileShare -Context $ctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name
$d
```

**Output:**

```
Name                      
----                       
files                      
1-12-2023.html             
28-11-2023.html            
29-11-2023.html            
30-11-2023.html            
Nov 15.html                
PostgreSQL on Azure VM.html
```

[image]

So, if you want to retrieve all shares in the storage account and then filter by name, you can use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet to iterate over the shares like the below command:

```
$S = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $ctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Name -eq $AzShare) {
        return $_
    }
}
```

This above command returns a share object with the name `$AzShare`, or `$null` if the share is not found.